# Hide/remove status bar from android source code (Android 6.0.1)

Tags: android, build, statusbar, imx6

I'm new to this forum, and first of all, i apologize for my English,

I have a question about Android 6.0.1, 
I'm customizing the operating system with the source codes for the IMX6 board.
It's possible to remove or hide the "status bar" (notification bar) on the top of the operating system by editing the build.prop file or others files?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score 3):

```
    public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

           @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

write this code in activity's onCreate method

```
   

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash); 
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, 
Do I have to create a new launcher right?

Comment: No, just put it in all activities' (screens) onCreate in which you want to hide the status bar.